# Configure Laravel app to use AWS SES without access key and secret key?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'd like to set up my Laravel app to use AWS Simple Email Service *without* requiring an IAM user's access key / secret key.

My Laravel app is running in an ECS-hosted container and I have given its task role an IAM policy which gives the container permission to use SES. I have fully configured and validated SES in my account, in the same region as my ECS cluster.

SES appears to require the following configuration in my `config/services.php` file:

```
'ses' => [
    'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
],
```

Is there a way I can amend this so that the SDK uses the IAM policy's permissions rather than requiring a key/secret for an IAM user?

Comment: Does this not work? If you don't set those environment variables it would usually fallback to using the task role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @apokryfos correctly points out, simply leaving the `secret` and `region` keys out of that array allows the SES mailer to fall back on any policy that the ECS task role has permission to use.

... stupidly I had applied said policy to the *task execution role* rather than the *task role*.